# iOS Custom Build Configurations and Frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've got an XCode project with a couple of custom build configurations (above and beyond debug and release) - alpha and beta.

That's fine for my project - but I also have dependencies on third party frameworks.  Those frameworks won't have an alpha and beta build configuration, and I'm currently forking them on github for the express purpose of simply adding new build configurations to those projects - so that my custom configurations can build.

Is there a better way to do this?  Can I use one build configuration for a framework (release), and a different for my app (alpha)?  I'm a bit lost in the byzantine XCode build system...

Also - how would something like Carthage help manage this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I'm having similar issue now.

Comment: nope... still doing what I think is a bit of hack to get this to work nicely... On the plus side, I'm finding do all this with git to be pretty easy.

Comment: have you tried this? http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2014/03/specifying-the-build-configuration-for-xcode-project-dependencies/

Comment: I'm currently doing the first part in that solution.  I just fork those dependencies (they're all on github) and add my special configurations in the fork... I'll look into scripting.  I thought it would be something like that, I just never did it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile a project with app and library in the same workspace with different configuration names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884778/how-to-compile-a-project-with-app-and-library-in-the-same-workspace-with-differe)

Comment: I believe this is the same core problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884778/how-to-compile-a-project-with-app-and-library-in-the-same-workspace-with-differe/30884779#30884779