# How to add environment configuration to workspace with multiple projects using xcconfig files

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcconfig

I created sample project to demonstrate the problem
https://github.com/pikciu/XCodeWorksapce/tree/noPods

- invalid paths to frameworks
- frameworks build in different configuration than main project.

There are 4 build configurations and 2 schemes. Every build configuration uses different xcconfig file.
[image: configuration]
Lib.framework is linked to the main project.

XCode builds frameworks in Release configuration even if main project is building in Debug.
[image: build fail]

I have found these solutions:
[Xcode Build Configurations in Workspace With Multiple Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426440/xcode-build-configurations-in-workspace-with-multiple-projects) and [How to compile a project with app and library in the same workspace with different configuration names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884778/how-to-compile-a-project-with-app-and-library-in-the-same-workspace-with-differe/30884779#30884779)

```
MODULES_BUILDS = $(DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME)
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(MODULES_BUILDS)
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS)/include
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS)
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe is it XCode 10 issue?

Comment: can you check out the targets again ?

Comment: @Tobi what do you mean? I didn't change targets. There is still one target

Comment: I don't get it. What is the question? I cloned your sample and I see no issues. Can you explain a little bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Lib target is being built with the Release configuration. Change this setting Under `Configurations` of your Lib project, use the `Debug` configuration for command-line builds.

[image]